# Friendly way to identify users in Firebase Analytics beyond UserID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm new to Firebase Analytics (or analytics in general). We have a new app with a few customers, <100.

We are attempting to get a more indepth look at our user behavior.  We are currently passing the Firebase user's ID and various properties (their role, organization, etc.) but it's difficult to know "who" the user is.  Rather than looking up the userId to match them to an individual (i.e. John Smith at Company XYZ) it would be nice to capture the user's info such as their username or email address.

Should we just pass this in as a user property?  Or is Analytics really too high level for this and we should be looking at something else if we want individual usage history like this?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass any information which a third party (incl. Google) could recognize as personally identifiable information to Firebase Analytics. In fact its against their policy. See https://firebase.google.com/terms/analytics#7_privacy

You can track personally identifiable information in your own infrastructure but should be careful exposing it to any third party.

There is also a note on the Firebase Analytics set user id documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid